# A question about composition of functions in set theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The question ask me to prove that if $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ and $g$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ such that $gf$ is the identity on $X$, then $f$ is one-to-one and $g$ maps $Y$ onto $X$.

I cannot see why $f$ must be one-to-one. For example, let $X=\{a\}$ and $Y=\{b,c\}$ and define $f,g$ such that $f(a)=b$ and $g(b)=a, g(c)=a$, then $f$ is not one-to-one?

Comment: Why do you think the $f$ in the example is not one-one? It *is* one-one. Please tell us your definition of one-one : we can sort out the confusion. Alternately, $g$ is also onto.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You claim that you “cannot see why $f$ must be one-to-one” and then you provide an example in which $f$ *is* one-to-one.

Comment: Because we say that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ but there is an element($c$) in $Y$ that no element in $X$ can map to, which means that the function is not onto. Since it's not onto, it is not one-to-one...

Comment: I'm sorry if I committed some low-level logical error here. By the way, I'm reading Halmos' excellent book, so I believe it must be something wrong in my understanding. :|

Comment: "Since its not onto, its not one-one" is a grave mistake. What about the definitions of "onto" and "one-one" makes you think that onto implies one-one? Neither implies the other in general. That $f$ is not onto is true, and your explanation is right. That it is one-one, is true because that definition is satisfied.

Comment: You know, a lot of people worked very hard on writing tag wikis and excerpts that should help you understand what questions fit under what tag. You're not new here, your reputation is over 1000 points. It's not the first question this week that you ask under [set-theory] that has no business being tagged [set-theory]. This behavior is borderline insulting to the effort put by so many people into the tagging system.

Comment: I think the confusion lies in that some people say "one-to-one" to mean injective, while some others say "one-to-one" to mean bijective.

Comment: Hi Asaf, I apologize for tagging with set-theory instead of elementary set theory. I didn't realize that was wrong in my last question. Until you said, I haven't noticed that these two tags serve different purposes here. Also, my reputation comes from answering other types of questions. I'm rather new with this "rigorous" version of set theory I'm learning currently - and I don't know if's truly elementary or not. What I'm aware was that Halmos introduces the axioms from ZFC set theory(except the foundation axiom) in his book. Please correct me if I'm wrong. @AsafKaragila

Comment: Thanks guys, I now finally realize that I messed up this one-to-one(injective) with bijective function I learnt before. What I was taught back then is a function is bijective only if it's injective and surjective. I'm sorry that I asked a really dumb question here...

Comment: @AsafKaragilaa.  The question is more acceptable than your rant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:X \to Y, g:Y \to X$ be functions such that $gf(x)=x$ on $X$.

Assume $f$ is not 1-1. Then there exists $y \in Y$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$, where $x_1 \neq x_2 \in X$. But now $gf$ cannot be the identify function on $X$ as $gf(x_1)$ and $gf(x_2)$ can only map to a single $x \in X$ (by definition of a function), a contradiction.

Assume $g$ mapping $Y$ to $X$ is not onto. Then there is an $x \in X$ such that $g(y) \neq x$ for all $y \in Y$. So then $gf$ cannot be the identity on $X$, again a contradiction.